# How do I declare global array in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to store an array value so that I can reuse when Sub is called more than once.
I would like to prevent from reassigning values to the array if value exist.

My code is something like this.

```
Dim views()

Sub runit()
    For i=0 To 3
        test()
    Next    
End Sub

Sub test()
        ReDim Preserve views(0)= "test"

       ' - other codes that I want to run-
End Sub
```

I get " Type mismatch :'choseviews'" error.

If I move "Dim views()" inside "Sub test", I don't get the error.
How do I declare global array in VBScript?
If it's not possible, is there any ways to prevent reassigning array when Sub is called?

This following code does not work but you may get an idea what I'm trying to do .

```
    Dim views()

    Sub runit()
        For i=0 To 3
            test()
        Next    
    End Sub

    Function IsArrayDimmed(arr)
       IsArrayDimmed = False
       If IsArray(arr) Then
         On Error Resume Next
         Dim ub : ub = UBound(arr)
         If (Err.Number = 0) And (ub >= 0) Then IsArrayDimmed = True
        End If  
     End Function


    Sub test()
        If IsArrayDimmed(views) Then

        Else
             ReDim Preserve views(0)= "test"

        End If
               ' - other codes that I want to run-
    End Sub
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it seems like you want to declare a global array variable, and then add items to that array, without being limited to a static number of elements. In other words, you need to dynamically increase the size of the array by re-allocating it.

The global declaration is correct and belongs where you have it:

```
Dim views()
```

What you wrote here is incorrect syntax, you cannot assign a value and ReDim at the same time.:

```
ReDim Preserve views(0)= "test"
```

Additionally, that would ReDim the array to size 0, which is the opposite of what you want.

If you wish to "push" values on that array you should use a function like this which handles the redim to increase the size of the array before adding the value to the tail of the array:

```
Function Push(ByRef arrTarget, ByVal varValue)
    Dim intCounter
    Dim intElementCount

    ReDim Preserve arrTarget(UBound(arrTarget) + 1)

    If (isObject(varValue)) Then
        Set arrTarget(UBound(arrTarget)) = varValue
    Else
        arrTarget(UBound(arrTarget)) = varValue
    End If

    Push = arrTarget
End Function
```

Use it like this:

```
Call Push(views,"test")
```

Answer (score 0):

Any variable instantiated in the global scope will be a "global" variable.  However, you should pass that variable explicitly into other scopes "by reference" if you want to have any changes persist in the original scope.  You can do that using the ByRef keword in your Function or Sub declaration.

```
Sub test(ByRef viewsArray)
```

Now within test you will reference viewsArray which acts as a pointer to views.